# Change SFTP user's permissions when transferring files to webserver

Tags: unix, permissions, raspberry-pi, webserver, sftp

I created a webserver and have two users that can login over SFTP to change, edit, view, and create folders/new files. When the two users create a new file, the permissions are -rw-r--r--. I need the permissions to allow writing from the other user as well, which they can't right now. I have tried changing the umask, sshd-config file, group permissions, etc, but I still cannot figure out how to fix this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The webserver is running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi. I installed Apache, PHP, MySQL, and PHPmyAdmin. I am connecting to the pi via SFTP from filezilla on a Mac.

Comment: "I have tried changing the umask, sshd-config file,…" – What *exactly* have you tried?

Comment: I changed the umask to 000 and added the line "ForceCommand sftp-Internal -u 2" to the sshd-config

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is SFTP as I am connecting over port 22, and I am using filezilla on a Mac. Thanks

Comment: I used FileZilla on Ubuntu. Confirmed, it can create files. But for me it creates files with respect to the remote umask. What is the OS on your server? Is there `sshd`? or something else (e.g. `dropbear`)? On what filesystem do you create new files? How is the filesystem mounted? Please [edit] the question and add this information there, along with any other relevant information from your comments (like a fact you're using FileZilla on Mac). The point is to let other users know everything important without them reading all the comments and picking information scattered there.

Answer (score 3):

I did some research for you.

My (local) client is Ubuntu, my (remote) server is Raspbian. I connect via SFTP using the client's `sftp` interactive command. I transferred a testfile with local permissions `-rwxrwxrwx` from the client to the server using this command within `sftp`:

```
put testfile
```

The remote copy inherited permissions, except some of them were masked by the remote umask, which was `0022`, so the remote permissions turned out to be `-rwxr-xr-x`. This is expected.

Then I edited the remote `~/.profile` to (temporarily) set umask as `0002`. After logging in again the new umask worked in the remote shell. I restarted my local `sftp` and tested again but the new remote copy didn't obey the new umask.

Not a surprise. In my remote `.profile` it reads:

> for setting the umask for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package

It turned out `libpam-umask` is in fact in `libpam-modules`. It had already been installed.

I read [this piece of documentation](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_umask.html). It gives an example:

> Add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/login` to set the user specific umask at login:
>
> ```
> session optional pam_umask.so umask=0022
> ```

I checked the remote `/etc/pam.d` directory and guessed I need to modify `sshd` file there, not `login`. Additionally I didn't want to pass umask globally to the module. The documentation says:

> The PAM module tries to get the umask value from the following places in the following order:
>
> - `umask=` argument
> - `umask=` entry in the user's GECOS field
> - […]

I chose [GECOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field), run `sudo vipw` and added `umask=0002` to my entry; saved. The result was:

```
kamil:x:1001:1004:Kamil Maciorowski,,,,umask=0002:/home/kamil:/bin/bash
```

Then I added this line at the end of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session optional pam_umask.so
```

After this I removed the remote copy of `testfile`, run local `sftp` anew and transferred the `testfile` again. The new remote copy obeyed my chosen umask.

---

Edit

I tried FileZilla on my local Ubuntu. It creates files on the server with respect to the remote umask; it copies local files with their local permissions also with respect to the remote umask.

With FileZilla one can change permissions of a remote file "by hand". I understand this is what you want to avoid.

(Edit ends here)

---

I think the procedure for you is as follows:

1. Take the above example and set umask for the two users in question, so remote files they create via SFTP are writable by group.
2. Crate a special group on the server, add the two users to it and make it their primary group.

(I won't explain point 2 in detail here. Do research; ask separate question(s) in case of problems).

This way every new file created via SFTP by any of the two users will belong to the special group and it will be writable by this group. Remember that files being copied preserve their permissions as far as they can (at least in my tests).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I really appreciate it. So I tried everything you said, but it seems to still give the users the default permissions. My user 'webuser' I changed to "webuser:x:1001:1001:,,,,umask=0000:/var/www/html/:/bin/bash" and added the line at the end of the sshd file. I am creating a file on filezilla on the raspberry pi server and the permissions for that file are -rw-r--r--. Do you have any ideas what I am still doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: In filezilla I can create a folder or file on the webserver. It creates an actual file in the html folder for the apache server. I can make a test1.html file on the server. I have been able to create new files through filezilla with other webservers. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think filezilla does anything else than creating the file with the default
permissions as specified on the remote server.

If you could change to using the OpenSSH SFTP client and server,
you may use `put` with the `-P` flag.

This creates the file, which always gets the normal permissions for the remote
server. But after the upload is complete, the client further asks the server to explicitly
(re)set the permissions to be the same as the local file via a `chmod` request,
for which the umask does not apply.

For more information see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/639055/18736).